# Changing color TabbedPannelHeader in Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

I tried many different ways, but nothing solve this.
When I change the color of a button, for (0,0,1,1) I have blue. If I use the same list for TabbedPannel, I have dark blue, and for (0, 0, 1, 0) I have white. Is like I have a black background and I always have a mix of it and any other color, but I'm not able to get the specific color. This happens on Spinner too, but not with Labels or Buttons. What should I do? I tried use default_tab_cls, but, as I could imagine it just changes the default tab.

Edition after first answer:

This is the part I having problem. I call a function that returns my TabbedPanelHeader. Everything is ok with this.font_padrao is a custom font and this is working well. This example returns me white background and blue color font. If I change background_color to (0,0,1,1) the blue is different from the blue I have when I do the same thing ins Button for example. There, the blue is "real blue", not a "dark blue" or something like this.

`return TabbedPanelHeader(text=nome, 
                         background_color = (0, 0, 1, 0),
                         font_name=fonte_padrao,
                         color = (0,0,1,1))`

Comment: you have not provided sufficient information ... please provide a small example kivy program that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Sorry Joran, I added more information now. The main problem is that I don't have the same background color in TabbedPanelHeader that I have in Button for example. Spinner shows a similar strange behavior for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on windows, so default background is black afaik, <s>but maybe on other OSes there is different one</s>.

In your `main.py`:

```
from functools import partial
import rotinas
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) <-----
import sqlite3 as sql
from datetime import *
```

That's your white color, if you use alpha==0 in your coloring. Remove that line and you'll have the default Kivy background i.e. *black*.

Next thing, `Label` itself has no image as a background, therefore changing its background color either with variable or with canvas instrucctions results in a clear color. In widgets such as `Spinner` or basically anything that has different color than transparent most probably uses an image from [`atlas`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html) as a background(setting stuff from canvas is less efficient than changing pngs - at least more lines of code).

When you use a widget that has an image as a background, changing the backgroung color *only tints* the image that's used as background i.e. the `atlas` one. There is your problem, because you maybe want to have a clear color or use the `TabbedPanelHeader`-blue(tinted one). Two examples:

Here you have the tinted blue(the `background_normal` isn't necessary, it's set like that by default by kivy)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    TabbedPanelHeader
        color: (0,0,1,1)
        text:'blaaaaaaa'
        background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
        background_normal: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/tab_btn'
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Here you have the standard, clear color(see the empty `background_normal`):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    TabbedPanelHeader
        color: (0,0,1,1)
        text:'blaaaaaaa'
        background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
        background_normal: ''
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

PS: **Use [pep8](http://pep8online.com/)** or install one yourself(`pip install pep8`) and make your code more readable. You will have *a lot* of problems debugging that after a year, trust me. It may work well, but you killed whole point of python readability.

Also I saw some `.db` files in your zip, but didn't open them. The thing that you posted your database to someone you surely don't have a clue what will do with it is bad. Worse is even that you posted it publicly. Let's say you have in that database personal data, bank account numbers or whatever - you don't want to be responsible for loosing or misusing them, do you?

Comment: KeyWeeUsr, thanks for the answer, but definitely this is not the problem. I put a picture here: http://doatlanticoaopacifico.com/app/problem_color.png Exactly the same tuple for the background, but different results. And more: in this example, the font and background are both (0,0,1,1), but we can read the text! Strange, no?

Comment: [TabbedPanelHeader](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv#L151) uses an image from default theme(atlas://) as a background and you have to use that image too, if you want to get the same result with the same coloring. Also, you definitely should include stuff like this(screenshots, snippets,...) into your question _first_ :P

Comment: I tried to do background_disabled_image='' and background_image='', but nothing changed. Also tried to set both to a existing figure, but nothing changed. But, as you said if I put a image all blue, with the blue I want, I can get the correct color, right?  But why can't I set the picture using background_image?

Comment: the variable has [different](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv#L154) name than "background_image", use it properly, it should work. And yes, when you use the colors properly, you can set whatever color you like. Pick [any color](http://www.colorpicker.com) and divide with 255(e.g. `R/255`), that's your value for the first number of (r, g, b, a). **To understand it properly:** if a widget has bg-image, with coloring you tint the image, if not, you set the color as background.

Comment: KeyWeeUser, I tried change background_normal,background_disabled_normal,background_down and background_disabled_down, all of them to nothing (setting ''), and tried to set them to an existing figure, one that I'm using in other parts of the App. The result is the same...=(

Comment: Would be better if you showed me some code, not only some widget return as in original post, which gives me pretty much no information.

Comment: KeyWeeUser, I appreciate your help! If you're interested, I put the complete code in http://doatlanticoaopacifico.com/app/dapapp.zip. I create a function to make easier new tabs (at least, for me). For change the colors in the tabs, look at lines 55-62 in modelos.py

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!
Thanks for the others tips too, hope write better codes in the future. And I noted an important thing: the behavior in Android and in PC are different. If I just use your old tips (setting all the backgrounds to nothing, in summary, what I already had done), in android this problem wouldn't appear. I changed Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)  to Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 0) and nothing changed on PC, but on android both options worked and made the "good blue". About db, I didn't send any personal data, but thanks for the tip too.